# Mysql grouping / order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Just wondering if this is possible at all. I have a table which has two columns, item and category which when I use the following SQL statement displays:

```
SELECT * from tableitems ORDER BY category;
```

Table:

```
item    category
aitem   AAA
aaitem  AAA
abitem  AAA

acitem  BBB
baitem  BBB
bcitem  BBB

aditem  CCC
bditem  CCC
caitem  CCC
```

Is there anyway in MySQL to display it like this in a single MySQL statement?

```
AAA
aitem   
aaitem  
abitem  
BBB
acitem  
baitem  
bcitem  
CCC
aditem  
bditem  
caitem
```

Comment: @hafichuk How to GROUP BY help this situation?

Comment: @Nonym This is not my question....

Comment: Arif :: so sorry :( @user1038814 ::  you mean that you want data from both columns returned in one single column? Just making sure

Comment: @Nonym yes, that is my intention. I was just wondering if it was possible to do so with one sql statement, failing which I'll just use php to manipulate it. Sorry, just dabbling in DB, just a freshie. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with a simple SQL statement. You can easily arrange the information to look like that on any client language you are using to access MySQL though...

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against it, but it *is* possible:

```
SELECT IFNULL(item, category) AS value
FROM
(
    SELECT category, item FROM tableitems
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT category, NULL FROM tableitems
) T1
ORDER BY category, item
```